# Datatables returns all rows instead 10

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

Here is my AJAX :

```
$('.customers-datatable').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        url: 'ajax/customers.php?action=list',
        type: "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "orderable": false, "width": "20px" }
    ]
});
```

Here is my PHP/MySql :

```
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM customers');

$req->execute();

$result['draw'] = 1;
$result['recordsTotal'] = $req->rowCount();
$result['recordsFiltered'] = 10;
$result['data'] = array();

while( $row = $req->fetch() ) {

    $result['data'][] = array($row['lastname'] . ' ' . $row['firstname'], $row['zipcode'], $row['city'], $row['email'], $row['telephone'], "");

}

$req->closeCursor();
```

So, instead getting 10 elements, I got the entire list. Here is a preview fo what is rendered :

[image]

Any idea on how to limit the table to 10 results ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked `limit` keyword?

`SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 0,10`

and in general `limit` would by combined with `ORDER BY some_column DESC` to give it more senses (say, by time or by id).

**Updated**:

to do pagination, just pass in different arguments when switch pages:

```
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 0,10 // 1-10 rows for page 1 
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 10,10 // 11-20 rows for page 2
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 20,10 // 21-30 rows for page 3
.... and so on
```

Comment: This query will fail for pagination.

Comment: @XavierC. you have nothing about pagination in your code

Comment: @XavierC. I just updated the answer with some ideas for pagination

Comment: I know how to limit the number of results using LIMIT argument, but unless I'm wrong, using datatables jquery script I don't need to use it because it will do the job by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pageLength` setting in datatables - such as

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
    "pageLength": 10 
});
```

This will output 10 rows

Comment: ok, can you create a fiddle so we can see what's happening - are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution to my problem.

Here is my new array of data :

```
$result['data'][] = array(  "name"      =>  $row['lastname'] . ' ' . $row['firstname'],
                            "zipcode"   =>  $row['zipcode'],
                            "city"      =>  $row['city'],
                            "email"     =>  $row['email'],
                            "telephone" =>  $row['telephone'],
                            "action"    =>  "<a href=\"#\" class=\"button-delete\" id=\"" . $row['customer_id'] . "\"><i class=\"fa fa-close fa-2x text-danger\"></i></a>"
                            );
```

And here is my ajax call (I've set serverSide to false because it broke the pagination) :

```
$('.customers-datatable').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    //responsive: true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": {
        url: 'ajax/customers.php?action=list',
        type: "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "zipcode" },
        { "data": "city" },
        { "data": "email" },
        { "data": "telephone" },
        { "data": "action",
          "orderable": "false",
          "width": "20px"
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: You should read the `start` and `length` parameters (you can use `var_dump($_POST)` for checking all the sent parameters) sent by datatables on the server-side for pagination. The server should be responsible for querying the DB (pagination. searching, sorting, ...), otherwise you don't benefit from all the options/flexibility that datatables provides.